# Scientific dependant visa refused!

Tags: france, schengen, dependent-visa, refusal, europe

My husband went to France (Roubaix/Lille) on a scientific visa (for PhD) on a scholarship. I applied for a long-stay visa a few months later. I am financially dependent on my husband, so I mentioned 'husband' in 'means of support'. A week later, they returned my passport and a letter of refusal.

The reason mentioned is no evidence of means of sufficient resources covering the entire period of stay. NOTE: the residence permit of my husband is work/employed category, not student. The amount he receives is ~1,000 euros each month. I attached bank statements of his French bank account of the last two months (as he created his account 2 months ago). I also attached letter of award of scholarship.

What could be the reason of rejection. What can I do to avoid chances of refusal next time?

[image]

Comment: As noted in the comments to your (now deleted) question on [Travel.SE], €1000 is not very much.    (Does he pay for his accommodation--and potentially for yours if you join him--from that money?)  You yourself noted that the minimum in Roubaix is over €600 per person, which is more than he receives.  The refusal seems unsurprising with that in mind.

Comment: I deleted the comments mistakenly.

Comment: I wanted to delete my question from Travel and repost it to Expatriates.

Comment: It really does look like the visa office are saying that he does not have enough money to support you as well as himself.

Comment: Okay, we are 200 euros short from minimum wage. 
I also work as a freelancer. Now, I have started working for two organization. They are based in different countries. Should I ask them to send me some letter/contract(to show with visa application) that I work for them (from home) and they pay me monthly. Would these letters  sufficient? or they may cause some trouble?

Comment: Yes, he pays for accommodation for both of us.

Comment: One thing I've found is that it's difficult in France to simply "work as a freelancer" paid from outside the country while living in France.  You could probably get away with it but it might be sketchy from a legal perspective, since technically you have to be "employed" from a French perspective and be paying into French social security.  You could certainly try it of course, but they might just disregard any means of self-support that isn't "French" enough. It's rather silly.

Comment: Can't I work in France as a registered Freelancers?

Comment: You can work as a freelancer in France, but it involves creating a one-person company, registering with the social security system for independent workers, etc. And, of course, for foreigners from outside the EU, getting a visa and residence permit. But if you work without paying social security and taxes, that'd be illegal.

Comment: Is registerating as a freelancer  and social security and paying taxes a tough process for foreigner?